# Not successful to load javascript into webView in android application

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I build application in android and I use in webView.
I want to load javascript into webVIew.

the target of  code javascript find text and mark it
this code of javascript

```
window.onload = function () {
  var bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var htmlNodeIterator = new HTMLNodeIterator();
  highlightText(bodyElement);
}   


function highlightText(node)
{

   var text = "android";
   var innerHTML = node.innerHTML
   if(innerHTML != undefined){
    var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
      if ( index >= 0 )
      { 
        innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0,index) + "<span style=\"background-    color:yellow\";>" + innerHTML.substring(index,index+text.length) + "</span>" +   innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
        node.innerHTML = innerHTML;

       }
   }
}
```

and this my code of android

read javascript file to string

```
 private String getScript(){
    StringBuilder markSectionsByScript = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        AssetManager assetManager = getContext().getAssets();
        InputStreamReader ims = null;
        BufferedReader br;
        ims = new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("script.js"));
        br = new BufferedReader(ims);

        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            markSectionsByScript.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(MessagesLog.APPLICATION,"throw exception when open or read from file:" + e.getMessage());
    }
    String script = "javascript:(function() { " +    markSectionsByScript.toString() + "})()";
    return script;
}
```

after webView finished in onPageFinished method I write

```
  webView.loadUrl(getScript());
```

and the code not working for me.
I load this url http://www.android.com/ into webView
and I try to highlight android word.
but is not work?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Android Webview doesn't support Javascript by default. You need to enable it manually:

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```